# What are the differences between "Ya Allah" vs "Allahuma"?

Tags: arabic, asma-ul-husna

I have a little but not much knowledge of Arabic.

Although **God** is called `Al-Karim`, I hear the invocation `Ya Karim`, but I never heard the invocation `Ya Al-Karim` or `Ya-l-Karim`. Same for other names of **God**: the definite article disappears from the vocative. Just as it would in English: `May the Lord have mercy on us` vs. `O Lord, have mercy on us`

One big exception: `Ya Allah`, which I've heard lots. (With definite separation between the end of `Ya` and the start of `Allah`, there are three different "a" sounds. I'm not talking about `yalla` as in `let's go`.)

Now I see that when my English translation of the Quran has `O God`, the original is `Allahuma`. I don't know anything like this construction, where someone is addressed by tacking "-uma" at the end or something similar.

Though as I say, I'm not at all knowledgeable in Arabic and might easily have missed something. So is there a difference? Is `Ya Allah` in the Quran and I missed it? Is `Allahuma` preferred? Is `Allahuma` a unique construction?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam.SE, we suggest you read the [FAQ](http://islam.stackexchange.com/faq), in it is what you need to know about how things work here.  We are looking forward to having you as an active participant.

Answer (score 7):

When I call someone in English, I would just say, for example:

> Mohammad! dinner is ready.
>
> محمد! العشاء جاهز

In Arabic, we have what's called *calling prefixes*. These prefixes are used before the name of what is being called (Huroof AnNada'), the callee (Al Munada).

There are a number of these calling prefixes, but *ya يا* is the most used one. So, when I want to call someone in Arabic I would say:

> Ya Mohammad! dinner is ready.
>
> يامحمد! العشاء جاهز

By the way, it's not correct to say:

> Ya Al-Karim. ياالكريم
>
> Ya Al-Muslim. ياالمسلم

Ya يا and ال Al (witch is the same as *the* in English) don't fit together. The correct usage is:

> Ya Karim. ياكريم
>
> Ya Muslim. يامسلم

By dropping Al, but the *Al* in Allah is part of the word so you don't drop it.

As far as *Allahumma* اللهمّ, Allahumma is a rare grammar. It has exactly the same meaning as *Ya Allah* ياالله, , the same two words but in one form.

What happened, I don't know how, is that, the calling prefix ya يا was dropped and an additional suffix that sounds *umma* ـمّ was added to *Allah* Allah-umma الله-ـمّ:

> Ya Allah, guide me to the right path.

The same as:

> Allahumma, guide me to the right path.

This is a rare usage. As far as I know, *umma* suffix only fits with *Allah*. It's not correct to say *Mohammadumma* محمدمّ or any other name, but *Allahumma* اللهمّ is correct.

Comment: +1 for the simplicity of the answer, I just add that I think the ``umma`` suffix is used with **Allah** when making a __Dua'a__

Comment: So does this mean ``Ya Allah`` is also a unique usage (because ``Al-`` is kept)? Or is there other examples of where ``Ya Al-`` goes together?

Comment: @abdalAhad `Al` in Allah is *part* of the word, so we don't remove `Al` since that will change the word.

Comment: @Sp. Is ``Allah`` the _only_ name where ``Al-`` is part of the name? Or are there other examples?

Comment: +1 and jazakallahu khairan for an excellent answer. I hope there are more questions that you will answer related to the Arabic language.

Answer (score 0):

Salm alykm

Firstly you asked way we don't say ya al krim becouse AllAH names are nouns and adjective not like  any name like `Malik` but it has the same state you can't say `Ya al-malik` he will say you didn't call me .
for more information you can say but allah is name and we say `Ya-Al-lah` ? for Allah is like Allahuma it chanced from `Alalha` the a has been deleted

Secondly you asked why `allahuma` efferent from `Ya ALLAH` and its same meaning for that arabic scholar  said:

> للَّهُمَّ: ( اسم )
>   اللَّهُمَّ : كلمة تستعمل في النداء مثل : يا الله ، وقد تجيء بعدها إلاَّ ، فتكون للإيذان بنَدرة المستثنى ، مثل : اللهمَّ إِلاَّ أَن يكون كذا وقَدْ تجيء للدلالة على تيقن المجيب للجواب المقترن به ؛ مثل : اللهُمَّ نَعَم
>   اللَّهُمَّ: ( اسم )
>   صيغة نداء ودعاء مثل : يا الله ، حذف منها حرف النداء وعُوِّض عنه بميم مشدَّدة اللّهم ارحمني ، { قُلِ اللهُمَّ فَاطِرَ السَّمَوَاتِ وَالأَرْضِ }
>   اللَّهُمَّ اجْعَلْنَا شَاكِرِينَ لِنعْمَتِكَ وَتُبْ عَلَيْنَا إنَّكَ أنْتَ التَّوَّابُ الرَّحِيمُ : اِسْتِعْمَالٌ لِلنِّدَاءِ الحَقِيقِيِّ اللهُمَّ تَقَبَّلْ دُعَائِي
>   اللَّهُمَّ إلاَّ : صيغة استثناء تفيد إثبات ما فيه شك سيسافر اللهُمَّ إلاّ أن يكون قد غيَّر رأيه
>   اللَّهُمَّ نعم : صيغة تفيد تمكين الجواب في نفس السَّامع أيوسف قائم ؟ تقول : اللهُمَّ نعم

conclusion `allahma` and `Ya ALLAH` is same meaning but the ya has been deleted and switched by `huma` 
an allah knows the right

Answer (score 0):

I heard from a mufassir that "Allahumma" conveys a meaning of nearness not contained by "Ya Allah". Calling implies otherness whereas we all are dependent on Allah and only He is self-subsisting. Acknowledging this relationship adds sincerity to our prayers.

Answer (score -1):

The word Allah in Arabic means the deity/god in English and the guys who answered you in the past quotes above are incorrect, the word "allahuma" is simply a plural form of the word Allah which contains the plural suffix "hum as huma" in modern Arabic grammar in other Semitic languages this is common as well as in Arabic, one example is in the Arabic form in the word "kitabhum" which translates as "their book", so the same grammar rules apply to the Arabic word "allahuma" as well.

The same word is found in Aramaic/Hebrew as elohim/alahyim found in the Torah in Barashiyth/Genesis 1:1 that they mistranslate as "God" yet in the Torah in Genesis it uses "us/we" when creating man/Adam, and the same is found in the Quraan in suratul a'laq where it uses the Arabic word "nahnu/we/us" when it states that al Insaan as man was created.

Comment: "the word "allahuma" is simply a plural form of the word Allah which contains the plural suffix "hum as huma" " - Please provide references for this. AND for this: "The same word is found in Aramaic/Hebrew as elohim/alahyim found in the Torah in Barashiyth/Genesis 1:1 that they mistranslate as "God""

Answer (score -2):

Watch answer on Facebook video:

[www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=763112737073042](http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=763112737073042)

Or watch on youtube starting at 6:10 in the following video:

[www.youtube.com/watch?v=X_iJwSVSuYU?t=6m10s](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X_iJwSVSuYU)

Basic answer:

The 'Meem Mushaddad' is used for emphasise. So 'Allahumma' is saying "Allah" with greater emphasise which calls all the attributes of Allah.